# how to insert to database value from Vue MultiSelect

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

im create a multi select form using Vue MultiSelect that i install from this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-search-select

here my form

```
<form @submit.prevent="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<multi-select v-model="single.artistname" :options="artist"
                        :selected-options="items"
                        placeholder="select item"
                        @select="onSelect">
                </multi-select>
</form>
```

and this my data return

```
data() {
            return {
                files: [],
                errors: [],
                single: {},
                image: '',
                success: '',
                artist: [],
                searchText: '',
                items: [],
                lastSelectItem: {}
            }
        },
```

my add script

```
    add(e) {
    let formData = new FormData();
formData.append('artist[]', this.$data.single.artistname);
     axios.post('/select-files', formData, config)
                        .then((response) => {
                            alert('Data Single Successfull Inserted.')
                            //this.$router.push('/single/');
                        })
    }
```

how to make my multi-select produce an array?

so i can input the data to database with simple looping in controller.

Comment: Just Assign array in data like this  single.artistname:[]

Comment: After that Just assign in append  
formData.append('artist', this.$data.single.artistname);

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 0):

After multi-selection, we get an array, just convert that array into json-data and store it in database with table-field of text data-type

during access, reverse same convert json-data into array and process further

you can use json_encode() and json_decode() php-functions

Answer (score 0):

I did same thing with Checkboxes

```
<b-form-checkbox-group id="checkboxes2" name="flavour2" v-model="cat_id">
                  <b-col sm='6' v-for="item in categories" :key='item.id'>
                  <b-form-checkbox v-bind:value="item.id">{{ item.category }}</b-form-checkbox><br/>
                  <b>Details:</b> <span>{{ item.item_details }}</span>
                   </b-col>
                  </b-form-checkbox-group>
```

Data

```
data() {
           return {
        errors:[],
        cat_id:[],
    }
    }
```

And finally

```
formData.append('cat_id', cat_id);
```

Comment: its different i think